# What are geodetic planes in the context of hyperbolic surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Could anyone help me understand what geodetic plans mean in the context of hyperbolic surfaces?

I've already searched the internet, but I can not find anything I want.

Here is a print of the article I'm reading:[image]

Comment: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Totally_geodesic_submanifold